# Mounting NFS via systemd in Centos 7

Tags: centos, systemd, nfs

I am trying to mount an NFS share on a CentOS 7 box using systemd. This is my **/etc/fstab** entry:

```
10.0.0.104:/export   /mnt       nfs  users,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,timeo=14,noatime 0 0
```

On boot or by entering ***mount -a*** has no effect, the partition is not mounted. Nothing seems to be logged either from what I can see.

If I mount it from the CLI with the same options however it works:

```
mount -t nfs -o users,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,timeo=14,noatime 10.0.0.104:/export /mnt
```

Any idea why it might be failing when not calling it using the mount CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man mount`:

> mount -a [-t type] [-O optlist]
>
> (usually given in a bootscript) causes all filesystems mentioned in fstab (of the proper type and/or having or not having the proper options) to be mounted as indicated, except for those whose line contains the **noauto** keyword.

From `systemd.mount` [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html):

> `noauto, auto`
>
> With `noauto`, this mount will not be added as a dependency for `local-fs.target`. This means that it will not be mounted automatically during boot, unless it is pulled in by some other unit. Option `auto` has the opposite meaning and is the default.

As you can see, any `/etc/fstab` line with `noauto` won't automatically mount when using the `mount -a` command.

You have `noauto` in your `/etc/fstab`. If you were to remove this, then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

it should also be noted that, after adding `x-systemd.automount` to an `fstab` line, you need to run:

```
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then one, or both, of the following:

```
  sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
  sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

only then will the automount will become active and usable.